# How to display the data based on the month in ag-grid (angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

**[Here's the Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world-jddkir?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

***list.component.ts***

```
 gridApi: GridApi;

      columnDefs = [] as any;
      monthNames = [
        {
          "monthName": "January"
        },
        {
          "monthName": "February"
        },
        {
          "monthName": "March"
        },
        {
          "monthName": "April"
        },
        {
          "monthName": "May"
        },
        {
          "monthName": "June"
        },
        {
          "monthName": "July"
        },
        {
          "monthName": "August"
        },
        {
          "monthName": "September"
        },
        {
          "monthName": "October"
        },
        {
          "monthName": "November"
    },
    {
      "monthName": "December"
    }
  ];
rowData: BehaviorSubject<Array<any>> = new BehaviorSubject([]);

  data = [
    {
      "code": "Machine 1",
      "assetCode": "PRN",
      "assetCount": 12,
      "date": "2019-05-18 00:00:00"
    },
    {
      "code": "Machine 1",
      "assetCode": "PRN 1",
      "assetCount": 10,
      "date": "2019-01-19 00:00:00"
    },
    {
      "code": "Machine 2",
      "assetCode": "PRN 1",
      "assetCount": 3,
      "date": "2019-01-20 00:00:00"
    },
    {
      "code": "Machine 3",
      "assetCode": "PRN",
      "assetCount": 1,
      "date": "2019-01-21 00:00:00"
    },
    {
      "code": "Machine 4",
      "assetCode": "PRN 1",
      "assetCount": 3,
      "date": "2019-06-22 00:00:00"
    },
    {
      "code": "Machine 5",
      "assetCode": "PRN 1",
      "assetCount": 3,
      "date": "2019-03-23 00:00:00"
    }
  ];

      constructor() {}

      onGridReady(event) {
        this.gridApi = event.api;
        this.setAgGrid();
      }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.setAgGrid();
      }

      setAgGrid() {
        for (let i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {
          const data = {
            headerName: this.monthNames[i].monthName,
            field: this.monthNames[i].monthName,
            width: 100,
            children: [
              {
                headerName: 'Style/Machine',
              },
              {
                headerName: 'Total',
                field: 'total',
                columnGroupShow: 'closed'
              }
            ]
          };
          // data.children.push(
          //   {
          //     headerName: 'PRN',
          //     field: 'assetCode',
          //     columnGroupShow: 'open'
          //   },
          //   {
          //     headerName: 'Total',
          //     field: 'total',
          //     columnGroupShow: 'open'
          //   }
          // );
          this.columnDefs.push(data);
        }
      }

    }
```

How to display the data based on the month and based on the current year.

For the example
there's data.

```
data = [
    {
      "code": "Machine 1",
      "assetCode": "PRN",
      "assetCount": 12,
      "date": "2019-05-18 00:00:00"
    },
    {
      "code": "Machine 1",
      "assetCode": "PRN 1",
      "assetCount": 10,
      "date": "2019-01-19 00:00:00"
    },
    {
      "code": "Machine 2",
      "assetCode": "PRN 1",
      "assetCount": 3,
      "date": "2019-01-20 00:00:00"
    },
    {
      "code": "Machine 3",
      "assetCode": "PRN",
      "assetCount": 1,
      "date": "2019-01-21 00:00:00"
    },
    {
      "code": "Machine 4",
      "assetCode": "PRN 1",
      "assetCount": 3,
      "date": "2019-06-22 00:00:00"
    },
    {
      "code": "Machine 5",
      "assetCode": "PRN 1",
      "assetCount": 3,
      "date": "2019-03-23 00:00:00"
    }
  ];
```

then there's two "machine 1" same name it should be merge as 1 based on the `code`, `assedCode` and `date`.

NOTE: example for date if the two "machine 1" then it will based on their month if they are same. then it will merge also the assetCount will be compute as sum.

example

```
code: 'Machine 1'
assetCode: PRN
assetCount: 2
date: 2019-01-10 08:08:08
________________
code: 'Machine 1'
assetCode: PRN
assetCount: 2
date: 2019-01-25 09:08:08
________________
code: 'Machine 2'
assetCode: PRN 1
assetCount: 2
date: 2019-01-25 09:08:08
```

on ag-grid there's month which january to december then the data will be added based on the month.

```
January                          |February              |March               ..... etc..
Style/Machine   | PRN | PRN 1
Machine 1       | 4   |   0
Machine 2       | 0   |   2
```

it should be like this.
[image]

Comment: hi @ABC can you please update some more details about your output , like how you would like to show january and feb ,march...etc data in grid according to your data?
I wanna to know how it will be shown? in actual grid you have given e.g for janyuary but please update your feb and march as well with that sum

Comment: @kushalshah kindly check the latest photo. it created on photoshop